# Draw line path based on location's coordinates and attach icon features on it

Tags: openlayers, feature-layer

I want to draw a line on the map that indicates the path of the location based on its location coordinates and `begin longitude/begin latitude`, `end longitude/end latitude`

The target result is like

[image]

My approach is to implement the line path based on the location's coordinates first and then implement the render icons in the start/end points of coordinates

`handleGetMapPath.js`

```
// point is combination as the array of begin longitude/begin latitude and end longitude/end latitude
handleGetMapPath = async (point) => {
    // get map path events from api
    const { _getMapPath } = this.props;
    // map object in createMap event
    const { map } = this.state;
    await _getMapPath(point[0], point[1], point[2], point[3]).then((result) => {
      if (!isEmpty(result.value.data.getpath)) {
        const wkt = result.value.data.getpath;

        // format to line string
        const format = new ol.format.WKT();

        const feature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
          dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
          featureProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        });

        // get geometry from current feature
        feature.getGeometry().transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");

        const lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: "blue",
            width: 5,
            lineDash: [4, 8],
          }),
        });

        feature.setStyle(lineStyle);

        const multiLineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature],
          }),
        });

        map.addLayer(multiLineLayer);
      }
    });
  };
```

`renderPathIcons.js`

```
 renderMapIcon = (type) => {
    const { sctns, featuresLayer, map } = this.state;
    const { readOnly } = this.props;
    
    // get the start and end points for the icons 
    // E.g:
    // beginLa: 37.447734946
    // beginLo: 126.676537024
    // endLa: 37.444437172
    // endLo: 126.68087837
    const point =
      type === "start"
        ? new ol.geom.Point([sctns.beginLo, sctns.beginLa]).transform(
            "EPSG:4326",
            "EPSG:3857"
          )
        : new ol.geom.Point([sctns.endLo, sctns.endLa]).transform(
            "EPSG:4326",
            "EPSG:3857"
          );

    const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: point,
      name: type,
      population: 4000,
      rainfall: 500,
    });

    const iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "pixels",
        scale: 0.5,
        opacity: 1,
        src: type === "start" ? startPoint : endPoint,
      }),
    });

    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    featuresLayer.setSource(
      new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [iconFeature],
      })
    );

    if (type === "start") {
      this.setState({ startPinFeature: iconFeature });
    } else {
      this.setState({ endPinFeature: iconFeature });
    }
  };
```

However, the result is not as same as I expected before, the start/end points are getting a little distance from the real start/end point of the path.
[image]

Comment: To center the icon on the point use `anchor: [0.5, 0.5],  anchorXUnits: "fraction",  anchorYUnits: "fraction"`,

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the comments, I've updated the icon style but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you confirm tnat your `_getMapPath` method returns a path with the exact start and end coordinates - i.e. `feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate()` and `feature.getGeometry().getLastCoordinate()` might be points on the nearest major road?

Comment: @Mike `_getMapPath` does not return the exact start/end coordinates with the real begin long/lat, end long/lat

Comment: @Mike Do you know Is there any way to make it return the exact points?

Comment: I presume `_getMapPath` is calling a routing API.  Most only return routes via known roads.  If your requested start end points are off road you would need to extend the displayed line to include those (e.g. add a direct LineString from the requested start point to the returned first coordinate).